# ES6 functions, arrow functions and 'this' in an ES6 class

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6, es6-class, arrow-functions

```
class App extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    ...
  }

  onChange = (e) => this.setState({term: e.target.value})

  onSubmit(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    const api_key = "C1hha1quJAQZf2JUlK";
    const url = `http://api.giphy.com/v1/gifs/search?q=${this.state.term}&api_key=${api_key}`;
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <form onSubmit={this.onSubmit}>
          <input value={this.state.term} onChange={this.onChange}/>
          <button>Search!</button>
        </form>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

What is the difference between the two type of functions declared in the class **(onChange and onSubmit)**. I get an error on referencing this.sate in **const url** if I declare it as an ES6 class method but changing it to arrow function fixes it.

**I want to know how exactly 'this' is handled in both the cases**

Also, how do I do it the other way? Say, if I want to use the same onSubmit function (ES6 class method) but want to handle this when I call it (in the form element), how do I do it ?

*Using this.onSubmit.bind(this)* ?

Answer (score 29, accepted):

It's important to know that this syntax:

```
class A {
  method = () => {}
}
```

is just syntactic sugar for creating an instance method in the class constructor:

```
class A {
  constructor() {
    this.method = () => {}
  }
}
```

Note: This syntax is not an official part of the JavaScript language yet ([currently in stage 3](https://github.com/tc39/proposal-class-fields)) so you must use a [transpiler like Babel to handle it](https://babeljs.io/repl#?babili=false&browsers=&build=&builtIns=false&code_lz=MYGwhgzhAECC0G8BQ1oFsCmAXAFgewBNoBeaACgEoSA-RAX2iTqA&debug=false&forceAllTransforms=false&shippedProposals=false&circleciRepo=&evaluate=false&fileSize=false&lineWrap=true&presets=stage-2&prettier=false&targets=&version=6.26.0&envVersion=).

The value of `this` within `method` is the class `A` because that is what `this` points to in the constructor (since [arrow functions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions) inherit the context from the scope they are defined in):

```js
class A {
  constructor() {
    this.method = () => this;
  }
}

const instance = new A();
console.log(instance.method() === instance); // true
```

Defining a regular (non-arrow function) method on the class creates a method on the class prototype (not instance) but sets no rules on what `this` will be (since `this` is dynamic in JS and [depends on how a function is called, not how it's defined](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this)).

```js
class A {
  method() {}
}

console.log(new A().method === A.prototype.method); // true
```

If methods defined in either of these ways are called on the class instance (via the `.`), as per the rule of how `this` is bound when a function is called as a method of an object, `this` will point to the class instance in both cases:

```js
class A {
  constructor() {
    this.methodOnInstance = () => this;
  }
  methodOnPrototype() { return this; }
}

const instance = new A();
console.log(
  instance.methodOnInstance() === instance.methodOnPrototype(), // true
  instance.methodOnPrototype() === instance // true
);
```

One major difference between the two method declarations above is that the instance method has `this` **always** fixed to the class instance while the class (prototype) method does not (we can change it by using [Function.prototype.apply](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/apply) or [Function.prototype.call](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/call))

```js
class A {
  constructor() {
    this.methodOnInstance = () => this;
  }
  methodOnPrototype() { return this; }
}

const instance = new A();
console.log(
  instance.methodOnInstance() === instance.methodOnPrototype(), // true
  instance.methodOnPrototype.call('new this') === 'new this' // true
);
```

A common occurrence where the `this` changes is within an event handler, where the event handler calls the function passed into it and binds the context to the element on which the event happened (so overrides the value of `this` to be the element that was clicked or whatever the event was)

This happens in React as well for all ([synthetic](https://reactjs.org/docs/events.html)) DOM event handlers.

Therefore, if we want our method's context to always point to the instance of the React component, we can use the instance method.

Another way of restricting the context but not using the special instance method syntax that requires Babel is to directly create an instance method ourselves by creating a new function from the class (prototype) method with a bound context (using [Function.prototype.bind](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind)):

```js
class A {
  constructor() {
    this.methodOnInstance = this.methodOnPrototype.bind(this);
  }
  methodOnPrototype() { return this; }
}

const instance = new A();
console.log(
  instance.methodOnInstance() === instance.methodOnPrototype(), // true
  instance.methodOnPrototype() === instance // true
);
```

This allows us to arrive to the same result as using the special instance method syntax but with the currently available tools (ES2017 and under).

If for some reason we want a method that is always bound to something that is not an instance of the class, we can do that as well:

```js
class A {
  constructor() {
    this.method = this.method.bind(console);
  }
  method() { return this; }
}

const instance = new A();
console.log(
  instance.method() === console // true
);
```

Answer (score 1):

> An arrow function expression has a shorter syntax than a function
>   expression and does not have its own this, arguments, super, or
>   new.target. These function expressions are best suited for non-method
>   functions, and they cannot be used as constructors.

Arrow Functions lexically bind their context so this actually refers to the originating context.

In ES3/4 functions declaration you can use `this` by storing in some other variable.

```
const that = this;
onSubmit(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    const api_key = "***************";
    const url = `http://api.giphy.com/v1/gifs/search?q=${that.state.term}&api_key=${api_key}`;
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

> Also, how do I do it the other way? Say, if I want to use the same onSubmit function (ES6 class method) but want to handle this when I call it (in the form element), how do I do it ?
>
> Using this.onSubmit.bind(this) ?

Yes you must bind the method to the component in the constructor. It's because the arrow functions get automatically binded to the class therefore the scope of this is set in the method. While `onSubmit` is a regular function that is not yet binded therefore the this inside the method will reference the function and not the component.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `bind` in your class's constructor with the ES6 class method.  In essence, arrow functions do this for you automatically.

```
constructor(props) {
  super(props);

  this.onSubmit = this.onSubmit.bind(this);
}
```

The more important thing to note here is that I believe the arrow function here will be created on each instance of the class, where the ES6 class method will be made part of the class's prototype and shared amongst all instances.

Answer (score 0):

The key difference is that in ES5 we don't have auto binding which means you have to bind your event handler function manually in order to play with state or props inside the function in react. But in ES6 it does auto binding. That's the key difference

ES5: you have to bind onSubmit preferably in constructor

```
//is valid
this.onSubmit = this.onSubmit.bind(this);

onSubmit(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    const api_key = "C1hha1quJAQZf2JUlK";
    const url = `http://api.giphy.com/v1/gifs/search?q=${this.state.term}&api_key=${api_key}`;
  }
```

ES6:

The below is valid because it does auto binding.

```
onChange = (e) => this.setState({term: e.target.value})
```

Comment: No, it does not do auto binding. It simply doesn't put the function on the prototype.

Comment: Right. I understand that with the term auto binding:)

Comment: Binding means using `bind` on a generic (dynamic-`this`) method.