# set.State is undefined

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I have a variable in state called isLoading. The idea is to display a loading message while the program is communicating the server, then display the data. However, at ling 24, I get an error:

TypeError: This.setState is not a function (in 'this.setState({ isloadin: false});

```
import React from "react";
import { StyleSheet, Text, View, AsyncStorage } from "react-native";

var text;

export default class App extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    state = {
      isLoading: true
    };
  }

  componentDidMount = () => {
    AsyncStorage.getItem("accessToken").then(token => {
      postdata(
        "http://1.0.0.0:1337/loadTransactions",
        { UserID: 69 },
        function(result) {
          text = toString(result.Data[1].ID);
          text = result.Data[1].Label;
          console.log(result.Data[1].Label);
          this.setState({
            isLoading: false
          });
        }
      );
    });
  };
  render() {
    console.log(this.setState.isLoading);

    if (this.setState.isLoading) {
      console.log(this.setState.isLoading);
      return (
        <View style={styles.container}>
          <Text>Loading....</Text>
        </View>
      );
    } else {
      return (
        <View style={styles.container}>
          <Text>Hi, {text}</Text>
          <Text>Test</Text>
        </View>
      );
    }
  }
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    backgroundColor: "#fff",
    alignItems: "center",
    justifyContent: "center"
  }
});
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to access the correct \`this\` inside a callback?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20279484/how-to-access-the-correct-this-inside-a-callback)

Comment: Make sure how to use component state in react then use it, in your case remove the setState and log `this.state.isLoading` and use `this.setState({key:val})` when you need to set the state of the component

Comment: Unrelated, but `state = ...` should be `this.state = ...` in the constructor.

Comment: @JJJ that's related I guess :D

Comment: May be you are having error because of this "`console.log(this.setState.isLoading);`".
Remove that is you want the value of **isLoding** than console like this:"_`console.log(this.state.isLoading);`_"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To maintain the context of a function as the same context where the function was lexically defined, you have to use an [arrow function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions):

```
componentDidMount = () => {
  AsyncStorage.getItem("accessToken").then(token => {
    postdata(
      "http://204.48.23.161:1337/loadTransactions",
      { UserID: 69 },
      function(result) {
    // ^^^^^^^ use `result => ` here
        text = toString(result.Data[1].ID);
        text = result.Data[1].Label;
        console.log(result.Data[1].Label);
        this.setState({
          isLoading: false
        });
      }
    );
  });
};
```

Comment: ComponentDidMount() as an arrow function? That is some crazy new stuff.

Comment: That shouldn't matter for behavior. `= () => {}` is just a shorthand to define an instance method. Using this syntax makes the method be re-created for every instance where as using a prototype method maintains a single-copy for all instances but the behavior is unaffected either way.

Comment: See for more info: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48920135/es6-functions-arrow-functions-and-this-in-an-es6-class/48920356#48920356

Comment: The code works, but the console log still outputs "undefined" at     console.log(this.setState.isLoading), and when I set isLoading to remain true, it doesn't render the loading message, any idea why? Thanks!

Comment: @CalebBird As you were told in the comments, it should be `this.state.isLoading`, not `this.setState.isLoading`. `setState` is only for setting the state, not retrieving it.

Comment: I just tried that and it says "TypeError: undefined is not an object"

Comment: And that's because you have `state = ...` instead of `this.state = ...` in the constructor, which you were also told about earlier.

Answer (score 0):

`this` (ref to the instance of class) might not be available inside the context of `AsyncStorage`. Save `this` as another variable and use inside:

```
componentDidMount = () => {
  const self = this;
  AsyncStorage.getItem("accessToken").then(token => {
    postdata(
      "http://204.48.23.161:1337/loadTransactions",
      { UserID: 69 },
      function(result) {
        text = toString(result.Data[1].ID);
        text = result.Data[1].Label;
        console.log(result.Data[1].Label);
        self.setState({
          isLoading: false
        });
      }
    );
  });
};
```